# React: Material-ui tableRow can not choose, if using setState in onRowSelection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, state

I have a material-ui [table](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table)
[image]
 And I want to Pass selected rows to function in DELETE button.

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
            selectedRows: 'none',
      };
      }

  onRowSelection(val){
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({
      selectedRows: val,
    });
  }

render() {
<Table
              fixedHeader={true}
              selectable={true}
              multiSelectable={true}
              onRowSelection={this.onRowSelection.bind(this)}
            >
    ...
               <TableFooter adjustForCheckbox={true}>
                 <TableRow>
                   <TableRowColumn colSpan="5" style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>
                  <RaisedButton
                    primary={true}
                    label="DELETE"
                    labelPosition="after"
                    icon={<ActionDelete/>}
                    onClick={this.props.onDelete.bind(this.state.selectedRows)}
                  />
                   </TableRowColumn>
                 </TableRow>
               </TableFooter>
</Table>
}
```

I want to pass this.state.selectedRows to this.props.onDelete function, but as
reffered in this [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/3734), material-ui has problems with setState in onRowSelection.

How may I fix it, is there another way to access selected rows & pass them to some function and why such errors exist (why onRowSelection minds if I use setState on parent component?)

Comment: I think that selections disappear cause of that this.setState() does rerender, same effect with this.forceUpdate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an issue with material-ui's table resetting its checked status each render.
to overcome this problem you need to restore the checked state using setTimeout and manage the checked array by yourself. at least until this bug is fixed.
in the state, have this:

```
  state = {
    selectedRows: [],
  };
```

when rendering, add this:

```
            <TableRow key={index}
              selected={this.state.selectedRows.indexOf(index) !== -1}>
            </TableRow>
```

now that you maintain the checked status yourself you should have a function to accept check/uncheck calls, and restore uncheck all requests, like

```
  onRowSelection(selectedRows) {
    if (selectedRows.length === 0) { // due to a bug in material-ui
      setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ selectedRows: this.state.selectedRows }) }, 100);
      return;
    };
    this.setState({ selectedRows });
  }
```

and

```
      <Table
        onRowSelection={this.onRowSelection}
```

and

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onRowSelection = this.onRowSelection.bind(this);
  }
```

and you should also add a button to allow the user to uncheck all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the way you are using `bind` function. `bind` function's first parameter should be [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Syntax) and second parameter is what you want to pass to the resultant function. So you should pass function to `onClick` like this

```
onClick={this.props.onDelete.bind(this, this.state.selectedRows)}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not adress the problem.